# Android, This API is marked as internal to the support library and should not be accessed from apps error

Tags: android, lint

I'm using `invalidateOptionsMenu()` method to handle changing toolbar `MenuItems` but recently lint is highlight this method as an **`ERROR`** and says:

*`This API is marked as internal to the support library and should not be accessed from apps`*

Also for `navigationview.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(XXX);` method and some others! It's very illogical to use `@SuppressWarnings("RestrictedApi")` for solving this problem, because you are just ignoring the `lint` but not **solving** the problem.

how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 4):

If you're using support library and AppCompatActivity, you should call 
[supportInvalidateOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/AppCompatActivity.html#supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()).

Comment: Yes, but there is many of them, for example: `navigationView.getMenu();`
that `getMenu()` method has the same error

Comment: That was not part of the original question and is related to different class (AppCompatActivity vs NavigationView). But to answer that: Google seems to have annotated many methods in Support Library 25.0.1 with RestrictedApi (see http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks). You can ignore that with @SuppressWarnings("RestrictedApi"), but sometimes (as with the original question), there's a better way - not to use restricted methods and call those that Google created for that purpose.

Comment: You can post your code with getMenu as a separate question (please leave a comment here with a link) and maybe there's a way to solve that too.